# SwiftUI: On every Button click create a View and dismiss/delete it after a few seconds

Tags: swiftui

I want to create an effect if you press on a button a view should be visible above the button and fade away. I have already this effect:

```
struct AnimationView: View {
    
    @Binding var animate: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("-1")
            .bold()
            .opacity(animate ? 0 : 1)
            .offset(y: animate ? -50 : 0)
    }
}
```

My button which triggers `$animate`

```
@State var animate = false

Button {
    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
        animate = true
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
        animate = false
    }
} label: {
    'SomeView'
}
```

But my problem is that I only can have one of this View. I want to kinda spam the button which creates Views as much I pressed the button, which all fades away. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this label supposed to be hidden behind your button and move upwards or be invisible above the button and appear when clicked (I know it sounds weird to ask this but there is a reason).

Comment: @Alladinian I would prefer above the button

Answer (score 0):

You can change the @State property to this `@State var animate: [Your data type or Void if you don't need one] = []`. On each tap, you can append a `()` or any data type that you want and construct the views with that array, and then remove them with your timers.